# Why heatmap row order is not the same as the data row order?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

Hello for my work I creates a ggplot2 heatmap.

here are the data

```
structure(list(label = structure(c(4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 
1L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 
1L), .Label = c("SP1", "SP2", "SP3", "SP4", "SP5", "SP6", "SP7", 
"SP8"), class = "factor"), Categories = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR3"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("<NA>", 
    "A", "B"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

as you can see there is a specific order of labels :

```
1 - SP4
2 - SP5
3 - SP7
...
7 - SP8
8 - SP1
```

here is the df :

```
> table
   label Categories Value
1    SP4       VAR1  <NA>
2    SP5       VAR1  <NA>
3    SP7       VAR1  <NA>
4    SP2       VAR1  <NA>
5    SP3       VAR1  <NA>
6    SP6       VAR1  <NA>
7    SP8       VAR1  <NA>
8    SP1       VAR1  <NA>
9    SP4       VAR2     A
10   SP5       VAR2     B
11   SP7       VAR2     B
12   SP2       VAR2     B
13   SP3       VAR2     B
14   SP6       VAR2     A
15   SP8       VAR2  <NA>
16   SP1       VAR2  <NA>
17   SP4       VAR3     A
18   SP5       VAR3     B
19   SP7       VAR3     B
20   SP2       VAR3     B
21   SP3       VAR3     B
22   SP6       VAR3     B
23   SP8       VAR3  <NA>
24   SP1       VAR3  <NA>
```

so I'm expecting to see the same `row order` if I do a heatmap with ggplot, but instead I get this order:

[image]

I used the code :

```
ggplot(mod_mat_gen_env, aes(x=Categories, y=label))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Value))
```

Comment: If I use your data and plotting code, I get the y-axis order from SP8 (top) to SP1 (bottom). Anyhow, it depends on the factor level order of your `label` column. The first factor level will be plotted at the bottom and the last at the top.

Comment: Let's say I have a list in the right order I need : `list_correct_order=c("SP4","SP5","SP7","SP2","SP3","SP6","SP8","SP1")` how can I change the factor level of my label frm that?

Comment: Probably `factor(x, levels = unique(x))` would do the trick, where `x` is your already ordered character vector. Otherwise you might have to call `as.character(x)` first. So in your code: `mod_mat_gen_env$label <- factor(as.character(mod_mat_gen_env$label), levels = unique(as.character(mod_mat_gen_env$label)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to refactor it in your data.frame, or you can provide the order using `limits=` option in `scale_y_discrete()`

```
df$Value = replace(as.character(df$Value),df$Value=="<NA>",NA)
list_correct_order=c("SP4","SP5","SP7","SP2","SP3","SP6","SP8","SP1")

ggplot(df, aes(x=Categories, y=label))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Value)) +
scale_y_discrete(limits=rev(list_correct_order))
```

[image]